# C: array pointer pointing to its own address and carrying a value at the same time?

Tags: c, arrays

I am newbie in c

So in c,
if I do the following in main method,

```
int* a = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
a[0] = 1;
printf( "%x\n", a ); // 1d02230
printf( "%x\n", &a ); // 4bed1c00
printf( "%x\n", a[0] ); // 1
printf( "%x\n", &a[0] ); // 1d02230
```

This makes sense to me.
But when I do the following,

```
int b[] = {1};
printf( "%x\n", b ); // 4bed1bf0
printf( "%x\n", &b ); // 4bed1bf0
printf( "%x\n", b[0] ); // 1
printf( "%x\n", &b[0] ); // 4bed1bf0
```

This does not make sense to me... It looks like b is a pointer pointing to its own address, which also carries the value 1. I suspect It has something to do with b being a static array, but how do I make sense of this????

Comment: @CarlNorum: In the second example, `b` is an array of `int`, not an array of pointers.

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: @KeithThompson it was my mistake, I originally had a typo, I put down int* b[]. I later corrected it.

Comment: @CarlNorum: Sorry, I should have checked the edit history.

Comment: No problem. Comment removed; I fixed up my answer to match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointers and arrays aren't the same thing. Arrays *decay* into pointers to their first element in most contexts, but not when they're the argument of the unary `&` operator. That means your second example means something like:

```
printf( "%x\n", b );     // array name decays, 100% equivalent to &b[0]
                         //   type: int *
printf( "%x\n", &b );    // name does *not* decay, gives address of array
                         //   type: int (*)[1]
printf( "%x\n", b[0] );  // value of array element 0
                         //   type: int
printf( "%x\n", &b[0] ); // address of array element 0, same as line 1
                         //   type: int *
```

In contrast, your first example:

```
printf( "%x\n", a );     // value of pointer a
                         //   type: int *
printf( "%x\n", &a );    // address of pointer a
                         //   type: int **
printf( "%x\n", a[0] );  // value of element pointed to by a
                         //   type: int
printf( "%x\n", &a[0] ); // address of element pointed to by a (equivalent to a)
                         //   type: int *
```

Note that `%x` isn't the right format to be using for most of these print statements; you're lucky to be getting away with it, but strictly speaking that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: To print a pointer value, cast it to `void*` and use `%p`: `printf("%p\n", (void*)&a);`

Comment: For "value of array element 0" (i.e. b[0]), you say that type is int*. Shouldn't this be int instead?

Comment: I'll fix the answer to match.